# Disable vertical scaling in GTK+

Tags: c, gtk

How can I disable vertical scaling in GTK+? My program, which is currently only several controls in a few `hbox` objects stacked vertically in a `vbox`, stretches vertically when I increase the size of the window. I don't want this to occur.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more digging, I found out that the third argument to `gtk_box_pack_start`, `expand`, disables this behaviour when set to `0`.